# "Utilisability" vs. "usability"

Tags: nouns, suffixes, morphology

I tried hard to find if we have the noun *utilisability* in dictionaries but it does not exist. But, when goolging, I found some articles that contain this word.

I know that we have the verb *to use* and the corresponding noun is *usability*. I am just wondering if *utilisability* exists.

Comment: You could start by providing some links where you've found the word, instead of making us all scrounge the internet for a word that might not even be a word.  Also, what do you mean by "articles"? Pieces written by bloggers? Or material vetted through editors?

Comment: FWIW (from OED): Quick search results:  
No dictionary entries found for ‘utilisability’.  
  
Check your search and try again.  
Widen search? Find ‘utilisability’ in: » phrases (0)» definitions (0)» etymologies (0)» quotations (0)» full text (0)

Comment: Here is an example picked from an official book: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0038092X96001090

Comment: @J.R. ~ ["The utilisability method is used to perform the calculation."](http://www.scribd.com/doc/50104286/29/Utilisability-method), and [Extending Routers Utilisability and Life Cycle through Automated Configuration Management](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1692730), both vetted by editors. Against that, COCA with 450 million words found nothing. My guess is that it is a technical word.

Comment: @J.R. I already mentioned that i don't found this word in the dictionary. That's why i asked.

Comment: @RoaringFish if it is a technical word there is not a reference ?

Comment: kaissun: (1) Sometimes the dictionaries have to catch up with language; that's especially true with technical jargon. (As an example, _email_ wasn't a word in the 1800s.) (2) Your example is interesting - thanks for posting it.  (3) As for my dictionary comment, that was mostly for others who have access to the OED, to save them some time from checking (the OED lists several hard-to-find words that might not be listed in less comprehensive dictionaries; that's the first place many of us will go for _is-this-a-word_ questions). @RoaringFish: Curiouser and curiouser; thanks for sharing those.

Comment: Apart from technical jargon, I suggest that "utilisability" could replace "usability" or "utility" if one wants to seem particularly pompous. In the U.S., it would presumably be spelled "utilizability" unless one wants to seem both pompous and British.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[utilizable](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=utilizable)
capable of being put to a profitable or practical use

It turns out that the term *utilisability*/ *utilizability* has been adopted by literature in solar energy for a specific technical meaning. Most probably, owing to a first reference 'Utilisibility Method' by its proponent sometime earlier. Moreover, the original coinage could have been by a non-native speaker (or even a native speaker) who wanted, naturally, a new term to distinguish from the generic '*usability*'.

Comment: or a native speaker who wanted, for some reason, to distinguish the word from "usability".

Answer (score 0):

As noted in another answer, *utilisability* may be some kind of jargon or marketing term.  (Although I doubt it.)  In common usage, deriving *utilisability* from *utilisable* would an example of [overgeneralization](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/overgeneralization).  A noun with the intended meaning already exists: ***utility***.

Answer (score 0):

Utilisability can be found in design and ergonomics fields as an assessment of the user's ability to access and browse the provided content of an interface (device/website/software/video game...).

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This is interesting information; can you offer any supporting references or published examples to back up your assertions?