# Is the word utilisability correct

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Utilisability” vs. “usability”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84070/utilisability-vs-usability)

The word utilisability seems to come from the french utile (useful), utilisabilité (usability). I checked dictionary.com and some other online dictionaries, but without any result. However, when searching google, this word seems to be used in research papers, but mostly by french students. Is this word correct?